# Shorten code which handles IO

Tags: scala, haskell

I have written a small piece of code which handles the input of a console:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- readLine "> "
  loop input

loop :: String -> IO ()
loop input = do
  case input of
    [] -> do
      new <- readLine "> "
      loop new
    "quit" ->
      return ()
    _ -> do
      handleCommand input
      new <- readLine "> "
      loop new

handleCommand :: String -> IO ()
handleCommand command = do
  case command of
    "a" -> putStrLn "it was a"
    "b" -> putStrLn "it was b"
    _ -> putStrLn "command not found"

readLine :: String -> IO String
readLine prompt = do
  putStr prompt
  line <- getLine
  return line
```

The code works fine, but it looks ugly and is redundant. In Scala I succeeded to write it shorter:

```
object Test extends App {
  val reader = Iterator.continually(readLine("> "))
  reader takeWhile ("quit" !=) filter (_.nonEmpty) foreach handleCommand

  def handleCommand(command: String) = command match {
    case "a" => println("it was a")
    case "b" => println("it was b")
    case _ => println("command not found")
  }
}
```

I tried to use higher-order functions with the IO Monad in Haskell but I failed. Can someone give me an example how to shorten the Haskell code?

Another problem is that the order of output is different. In Scala it is correct:

```
$ scala Test
> hello
command not found
> a
it was a
> b
it was b
> quit
```

Whereas in Haskell it is not:

```
$ ./test
hello
> command not found
a
> it was a
b
> it was b
quit
> %
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import System.IO

main = putStr "> " >> hFlush stdout >> getLine >>= \input ->
    case input of
        "quit" -> return ()
        "a"    -> putStrLn "it was a" >> main
        "b"    -> putStrLn "it was b" >> main
        _      -> putStrLn "command not found" >> main
```

Shorter and clearer than Scala imo.

Comment: The Scala can be made shorter also, incidentally, using essentially the same layout as you have here.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a more concise Haskell version with the prompt printed as you'd expect:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = readLine "> " >>= loop

loop :: String -> IO ()
loop ""     = readLine "> " >>= loop
loop "quit" = return ()
loop input  = handleCommand input >> readLine "> " >>= loop

handleCommand :: String -> IO ()
handleCommand "a" = putStrLn "it was a"
handleCommand "b" = putStrLn "it was b"
handleCommand _   = putStrLn "command not found"

readLine :: String -> IO String
readLine prompt = putStr prompt >> hFlush stdout >> getLine
```

If you want to avoid explicit recursion you can use `Control.Monad.forever` (which has a strange and beautiful type, by the way: `Monad m => m a -> m b`):

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ putStr "> " >> hFlush stdout >> getLine >>= handleCommand
  where
    handleCommand ""     = return ()
    handleCommand "quit" = exitSuccess
    handleCommand "a"    = putStrLn "it was a"
    handleCommand "b"    = putStrLn "it was b"
    handleCommand _      = putStrLn "command not found"
```

See [this FAQ answer](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC%3aFAQ#If_I_print_out_a_string_using_putStr.2C_and_then_attempt_to_read_some_input_using_hGetLine.2C_I_don.27t_see_the_output_from_the_putStr.) for a discussion of why the prompt gets printed "out of order" without the `hFlush stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

The scrambled output appears because `stdout` is line-buffered (it only writes to the terminal once every newline). You should either switch to `stderr`, which is what you **always should use for interactive applications**, or you should turn off buffering for `stdout`:

```
import System.IO
-- ...
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

The rest of the code is pretty concise, but you don't have to have a separate loop function:

```
main = do
  command <- readLine "> "
  case command of
    "quit" -> return ()
    ""     -> main
    _      -> handleCommand command >> main
```

You can of course also avoid the extra `case..of` expression and some of the `do` blocks, but some people prefer to use your more explicit style.

Comment: "always" (using `stderr` for interactive applications) seems a little harsh. Haskell's own `System.IO.interact` writes to `stdout`.

Comment: "switch to `stderr`, which is what you always should use for interactive applications" - I heartily disagree; can you cite a credible source for this advice? stderr is intended *for error messages*. Switching the buffering is also unnecessary and sometimes overkill; just use `hFlush`.

Comment: The reason for using `stderr` for interaction is that it allows you to pipe the output of the command into a different command, and still see the interactive status of the program. `stdout` is generally used for data and `stderr` for user information. Examples of standard Unix tools that come to mind and that exhibit this behavior include `curl`, `pv`, `dd`, `cat`, `tr` and others.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt str = putStr str >> hFlush stdout >> getLine

main :: IO ()
main = do
  cmd <- prompt "> "
  case cmd of
    "" -> main
    "quit" -> return ()
    _ -> putStrLn (handleCommand cmd) >> main

handleCommand :: String -> String
-- define the usual way
```

If you're trying to transliterate the Scala you might try this, though it would be **wrong**:

```
promptForever :: String -> IO [String]
promptForever str = sequence (repeat $ prompt str)

main = do
  reader <- promptForever "> "
  forM_ (takeWhile (/= "quit") . filter (not . null) $ reader)
    (putStrLn . handleCommand)
```

The problem, amusingly, is that in this case Haskell is too strict: it will, indeed, prompt you forever, even though you might hope that it would spit out answers along the way due to laziness. The concept of `Iterator.continually(readLine("> "))` simply cannot (as far as I am aware) be directly translated into Haskell, due to how Haskell's IO works with the type system.

Comment: The iterator could technically be implemented using `unsafeInterleaveIO`, but letting pure code control how many times the terminal is read is of course... unsafe and very non-pure.